# Summation of the multipole expansions

Tags: special-functions, summation

Let $ \vec\Omega, \vec\Omega' $ be two unit vectors in $ \mathbb R^3 $ such that $ \vec\Omega\cdot\vec\Omega' = t $ and let $ r > 0 $. The multipole expansion for the exponential reads:

$$
     \mathrm e^{\mathrm i r t} = 4\pi \sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^l \mathrm i^l j_l(r)Y_{lm}(\vec\Omega)Y^*_{lm}(\vec\Omega') \\ 
     = \sum_{l=0}^\infty (2l+1)\mathrm i^l j_l(r) P_l(t).
$$

In *Mathematica* this series is given by:

```
Sum[(2 l + 1) I^l SphericalBesselJ[l, r] LegendreP[l, t], {l, 0, ∞}]
```

However, it seems that *Mathematica* is unable to compute this and similar series, for example:

$$
 \sum_{l=0}^\infty (2l+1) j_l^2(r) P_l(t) = \mathrm{sinc}(r\sqrt{2-2t}).  
$$

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Where do you have this identity from?

Comment: @Henrik, the first example is a special case of [this identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.23.E9). That being said, I do not recall *Mathematica* ever being equipped to handle these general sums.

Comment: Erm. I meant the second one with `Sinc`... Sorry.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher The second identity follows from the first one and from the identity (3) of https://mathoverflow.net/q/149692/17896. If you want, I can write a detailed derivation

Comment: @Appliqué Well, I would not have time and expertise to check it. I just wanted to make sure that the issue is really about Mathematica...

Comment: Mathematica is not a magic box that'll spit out a solution to any problem.Only [WRI](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?source=nav) can fix that.But $\sum _{l=0}^{\infty } (2 l+1) j_l(r){}^2 P_l(t)=\text{sinc}\left(r \sqrt{1-t}\right)$ is not **true**

Comment: You can check it: `w[r_, t_] := 
 Sum[(2 l + 1)*SphericalBesselJ[l, r]^2*LegendreP[l, t], {l, 0, 
    25}] // N; Plot3D[{Sinc[r*Sqrt[1 - t]], w[r, t]}, {r, 0, 2}, {t, 
  0, 2}]` **???**

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank you. A factor of 2 was missing. Now it is okay: `w[r_, t_] := 
 Sum[(2 l + 1)*SphericalBesselJ[l, r]^2*LegendreP[l, t], {l, 0, 
    25}] // N; Plot3D[{Sinc[r*Sqrt[2 - 2 t]], w[r, t]}, {r, 0, 2}, {t,
   0, 2}]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not available in the present version (V11.3 ).